# The project in TFS could not be load by other users in the team

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

After I created a new project and checked in TFS, others in my team could see this project.

They could get files from TFS successfully but just couldn't open the project in VS. Got a error seems virtual directory  created failed and configuration filed didn't load.

Have no idea how this means, what's the virtual directory point to?

By the way others in my team did't have the project admin permission(I have), no sure if this matters.

Deeply appreciate any suggestions you may have to offer.

Comment: You need to add more details on what error you see in order for others to help you. There is a good chance that you forgot to add one or more files in to the repository or you might have a different workspace hierarchy on the two machines.

Comment: Its very difficult to answer your question based on information. I don't think it's a TFS question either. 

It would appear that you are creating a web application project binding it to a virtual directory that might be tied to your machine. Edit your csproj file and find the the property <UseIIS> and set it the value to false. Others would be able to open up your project

Comment: Thanks for your guys, I have narrow down the issue to this specific project, some other test .txt files  could edit properly. My co-workers  told me this may related workspace. I also use an old server workspace for testing, this project couldn't even checked out by others. Are there some wrong source control binding with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use server workspace, you need to check **Enable multiple check-out**   in  *Team Project Settings -> Source Control -> Checkout Settings*

[image]
This option is always enabled in local workspace. For more details you could take a look at this question: [Enable Multi check out files at TFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15571695/enable-multi-check-out-files-at-tfs)

---

Just as *Hamid Shahid* mentioned in the comment, according to the error message, this may related to your project settings, open the `.csproj` file in a txt and find the `<UseIIS>True</UseIIS>` such as below:

```
<ProjectExtensions>
    <VisualStudio>
      <FlavorProperties GUID="{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21}">
        <WebProjectProperties>
          <UseIIS>True</UseIIS>
          <AutoAssignPort>True</AutoAssignPort>
          <DevelopmentServerPort>15165</DevelopmentServerPort>
          <DevelopmentServerVPath>/</DevelopmentServerVPath>
          <IISUrl>http://localhost:15165/</IISUrl>
          <NTLMAuthentication>False</NTLMAuthentication>
          <UseCustomServer>False</UseCustomServer>
          <CustomServerUrl>
          </CustomServerUrl>
          <SaveServerSettingsInUserFile>False</SaveServerSettingsInUserFile>
        </WebProjectProperties>
      </FlavorProperties>
    </VisualStudio>
  </ProjectExtensions>
```

Change the value to **false**, reload the project, check in the pending changes and try it again.